# jQuery Live Calculation Round Answer

Tags: jquery, math, jquery-calculation

The below solution works great for a simple live calculation however, I am trying to make one small change. I want to round the answer always to 2 decimal places. I have tried adding .toFixed(2) to various points but it doesn't seem to work. Like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mytextfield").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')
   var totalcost= $("#totaldays").val() * $(this).val() 
   $(".total_cost").text(totalcost).toFixed(2);
})
});
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve two decimal places?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseFloat(yourstring)` to convert string to number and try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytextfield").on('keyup',function(){
        var totalcost = parseFloat($("#totaldays").val()) * parseFloat($(this).val())
        $(".total_cost").text(totalcost.toFixed(2));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use divided by 100 at the end of it the syntax is like this:

```
/ 100
```

Also you need Math.floor of Math.round

Answer (score 0):

try this

> $(".total_cost").text(totalcost.toFixed(2));